# Unit test for custom error message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing tests for a React app using Jest and I am having trouble figuring out how to write a unit test expect case for a custom error message. The function I am trying to write the test for is:

```
export function maxSixCharacters(path, state, value) {
  if (value && String(value).length > 6) {
    throw new ValidationError("Cannot be more than 6 characters")
  }
  return true
}
```

`ValidationError` extends the `Error` class:

```
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  isValidationError = true

  constructor(message, errorMessage=undefined, secondaryCopy=undefined, ...args) {
    super(message, ...args)
    if (errorMessage !== undefined) {
      this.errorMessage = errorMessage
    } else {
      this.errorMessage = message
    }
    if (secondaryCopy !== undefined) {
      this.secondaryCopy = secondaryCopy
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to write something like this:

```
describe('maxSixCharacters', () => {    
  it('should throw an error if more than 6 characters', () => {
    expect(maxSixCharacters('', {}, '12345678')).toThrow('Cannot be more than 6 characters')
  })
})
```

This fails, however. How would I write the test case to make it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror), you need to simulate it's call inside the `expect` statement:

Change it from:

```
expect(maxSixCharacters('', {}, '12345678')).toThrow('Cannot be more than 6 characters')
```

to:

```
expect(() => maxSixCharacters('', {}, '12345678')).toThrow('Cannot be more than 6 characters')
```